# How to change display type to inline-element in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a weird issue with my inline block display

I have the following codes

```
 <section id='container'>
        <div id='left-nav'><a href='#'><img src='images/left-nav.png'/></a></div>
        <ul id='list'>
            <li><img src='images/slide1.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide2.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide3.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide4.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide5.png' /></li>
        </ul>
        <div id='right-nav'><a href='#'><img src='images/right-nav.png'/></a></div>
 </section>
```

css.

```
#container{
    width: 970px;
    height: 1px;
        padding: 5px;
    line-height: 190px;        
}

section #list {
    display: inline-block;
    display: none;  //I want to hide it when page first loads
}

section #list li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 162px;
    height: 142px;
    background-color: grey;
    line-height: 170px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 6px;
}

section #left-nav{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 120px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: none;  //I want to hide it when page first loads
}
section #right-nav{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 120px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: none;  //I want to hide it when page first loads
}
```

I want to display like the following:

```
left-nav    slide1 slide2 slide3 slide4 slide5    right-nav
```

It looks fine if I don't hide the left-nav and right-nav. However, my intension is to hide the whole section by default and display them if the user clicks a button.

I use the following js.

```
 $('#btn').on('click', function(){
       var height = $('#container').height();
       if(height>10){
           $('#container').height(1);
       }else{
           $('#container').height(190);
       }

       $('#list').toggle('slow');
       $('#left-nav').toggle('slow');
       $('#right-nav').toggle('slow');
})
```

However, it becomes something like this

```
left-nav    
slide1 slide2 slide3 slide4 slide5    
right-nav
```

`left-nav` and `right-nav` turn to block element instead of inline-element.

I am not sure how to solve this issue. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Add fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Bound content of "`left-nav`" in a div, may be set its class as "`content`", after that affect `.toggle()` with the content.
`$('#left-nav').toggle('slow');`
With other div are as same as above idea.
`.toggle()` function will change "`display`" attribute of selector by block (i think so ^^!)

Answer (score 0):

You should also provide `display: inline-block;` to the image as it's default behavior is differently works. If you define the property for image tag then only works as you have expected.

Answer (score 0):

In you case, when js use toggle to show the elements, `style="display:block"` are added into the elements like below:

```
    <div id='left-nav' style="display:block">
```

It covers item `display: inline` which in you CSS file. Your layout is broken.
If you want to show or hide the whole section, you can toggle the section instead "left-nav", "list" and "right-nav". Please look at the change like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #container{
      width: 970px;
      height: 1px;
      padding: 5px;
      line-height: 190px;  
      display: none;      
    }

    section #list {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    section #list li{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 162px;
        height: 142px;
        background-color: grey;
        line-height: 170px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 6px;
    }

    section #left-nav{
        display:inline-block;
        line-height: 120px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    section #right-nav{
        display:inline-block;
        line-height: 120px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section id='container'>
        <div id='left-nav'><a href='#'><img src='images/left-nav.png'/></a></div>
        <ul id='list'>
            <li><img src='images/slide1.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide2.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide3.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide4.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide5.png' /></li>
        </ul>
        <div id='right-nav'><a href='#'><img src='images/right-nav.png'/></a></div>
 </section>

 <div>
   <button id="btn">button</button>
 </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
       var height = $('#container').height();
       if(height>10){
           $('#container').height(1);
       }else{
           $('#container').height(190);
       }

       $('#container').toggle('slow');
    });
  </script>
</body>
```